# Auto populating data into an existing Excel template

Tags: sql-server, excel, templates

I was given an Excel template and have to automate filling it.

It is supposed to be uploaded every month into the grand central DB of our company. Grand central accepts nothing other than an Excel file with that template.

I tried reproducing the same using SSRS but it looks like SSRS has no control over rendering the looks and data in Excel (it keeps hiding columns and rows which is not acceptable). I have created a SQL connection on the Excel to get the stored procedure data into Excel.

Now I have to make sure the data goes into the template into appropriate fields. I think it needs groupings and page breaks also.

Please help..

Comment: You're not giving us nearly enough information to be able to help .... what does your stored proc look like, what data does it return? What does your Excel template look like - what data needs to be stored where??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with dumping SSRS as a way to export into the template. I've also found that the Excel rendering extension in SSRS does a lot of hiding and merging cells with certain report designs.

You will probably end up needing to write a script in your language of choice to load the data into appropriate cells on the template.

**Here are some Powershell articles on Excel automation:**

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel.aspx

http://winpowershell.blogspot.com/2007/03/powershell-and-excel-com-object.html

**Also take a look at Perl and the Win32::OLE module:**

https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=153486